# Using two arrays in calculations in Java

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, combobox, textbox

I have these two arrays that I want to use to display the high and low temps and the average of all the temps combined. For the integers, it is supposed to display the lowest temp and then the highest temp. So for each two integers in the array is to go with one year in the other array. How I would make it to where only two integers are displayed depending on the year selected? The yearTemp is used in a ComboBox and the 2 integers are to be displayed in un-editable textboxes.

```
/* 
 * Program Name: Temperature Average
 * Author: Cody Tapp
 * Date: July 12, 2018
 * Class: CIT 149 Java I
 * Description: This program will use temperature data from the past 65 years and use that info for the user to lookup
 * high and low temperatures for the month of January and the year selected. Displayed will be the average temperature for that month from 
 * all the years combined. 
 */

// Import gui components
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Comparator;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TapCoGuiTempAverage extends JFrame
{ // Begin class

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { // Begin main 

        new TapCoGuiTempAverage(); // Calls the TapCoGuiTempAverage method and executes. 

    } // End main

      String[] yearTemp = new String[]
{ "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954",
  "1955", "1956", "1957", "1958",
  "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962",
  "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966",
  "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970",
  "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974",
  "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978",
  "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982",
  "1983", "1984", "1985", "1987",
  "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991",
  "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995",
  "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999",
  "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003",
  "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007",
  "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011",
  "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015",
  "2016"};

    int[] highLowTemp = new int[]
{ 7, 68,  9, 77,  20, 65,  -7, 63,
 -3, 66,  8, 62,  -2, 63,   3, 58,
 -5, 69,  8, 70, -12, 58, -12, 71,
-28, 67, -6, 66, -14, 68, -15, 62,
 10, 73,  0, 64, -12, 60, -14, 66,
  7, 67, -8, 71,   0, 62,  13, 69,
  6, 70, -3, 57, -13, 41,  -6, 60,
  0, 60, 15, 56,  -2, 62, -19, 62,
 11, 57, -2, 61, -16, 63,  -7, 62,
 -2, 61, 18, 67,  13, 68,  14, 62,
  4, 58, 12, 67, -32, 54,   3, 69,
  7, 68, -2, 68,   6, 66,   4, 73,
  5, 69,  3, 61,  11, 72,  -8, 57,
  1, 70,  6, 69,  15, 65,   7, 67,
  1, 70,  0, 60,   2, 57,   3, 62,
 15, 64, 14, 68,  -4, 57,   2, 59,
  5, 64};

    // Objects declared that will be used in GUI
    private JButton buttonCalculate;
    private JButton buttonExit;
    private JComboBox<String> comboYearSelector = new JComboBox<>(yearTemp);
    private JTextField textHighTemp;
    private JTextField textLowTemp;
    private JTextField textAverageHighTemp;
    private JTextField textAverageLowTemp; 


    public TapCoGuiTempAverage() // Operate the GUI and processes all calculations based on selection in combobox
    /** REMOVE VOID TYPE TO COMPILE. **/
    { // Begin method

        // Sets window size, location, text, and close operation. 
        this.setSize(800, 400);
        this.setLocation(400, 400);
        this.setTitle("Daily Temperature");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /**** REMOVE COMMENT, ONLY HERE TO COMPILE UNTIL INNER ACTIONLISTENER CLASS IS WRITTEN.****/
        ButtonListener listen = new ButtonListener();

        JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel(); // Creates panel so objects can be added to the window.        
        JLabel labelYear = new JLabel("Select the year");
        tempPanel.add(labelYear);

        tempPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(15,6,0,5));

        String[] yearSelection = yearTemp; // ComboBox has a string array that will be used to display options in the dropdown menu
        comboYearSelector.addActionListener(listen); // ComboBox is added as an action listener and executes based on its selection.
        tempPanel.add(comboYearSelector); // ComboBox button is added to the panel. 



        JLabel labelHighTemp = new JLabel("High Temp:");
        tempPanel.add(labelHighTemp);
        textHighTemp = new JTextField(5);
        textHighTemp.setEditable(false);
        tempPanel.add(textHighTemp);

        JLabel labelLowTemp = new JLabel("Low Temp:");
        tempPanel.add(labelLowTemp);
        textLowTemp = new JTextField (5);
        textLowTemp = new JTextField(6);
        textLowTemp.setEditable(false);
        tempPanel.add(textLowTemp);

        JLabel labelAverageHighTemp = new JLabel("Average High:");
        tempPanel.add(labelAverageHighTemp);
        textAverageHighTemp = new JTextField(5);
        textAverageHighTemp.setEditable(false);
        tempPanel.add(textAverageHighTemp);

        JLabel labelAverageLowTemp = new JLabel("Average Low:");
        tempPanel.add(labelAverageLowTemp);
        textAverageLowTemp = new JTextField(5);
        textAverageLowTemp.setEditable(false);
        tempPanel.add(textAverageLowTemp);

        buttonCalculate = new JButton("Lookup Temp.");
        buttonCalculate.addActionListener(listen);
        buttonCalculate.setToolTipText("Looks up the temperature for year selected.");
        tempPanel.add(buttonCalculate);

        buttonExit = new JButton ("Exit");
        buttonExit.addActionListener(listen);
        buttonExit.setToolTipText("Closes the program.");
        tempPanel.add(buttonExit);

        this.add(tempPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);

    } // End method

        private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
        { // Begin inner class
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
            { // Begin method
                if(e.getSource() == buttonCalculate)
                {
                    String selectedItem = ((String)comboYearSelector.getSelectedItem()); 
                    // Get index of year array
                    for( int i = 0; i< yearTemp.length; i++)
                    {
                        if(yearTemp[i].equals(selectedItem))
                        {
                            int year = i;
                            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(yearTemp, year);
                            int lowTemp = highLowTemp[index*2];
                            int highTemp = highLowTemp[index*2+1];



                            String stringLowTemp = (Integer.toString(lowTemp));
                            String stringHighTemp = (Integer.toString(highTemp));


                            String displayLow = (String.format("%.2f", (stringLowTemp)));
                            String displayHigh = (String.format("%.2f", (stringHighTemp)));


                            textLowTemp.setText(displayLow);
                            textHighTemp.setText(displayHigh);

                        } // End inner if
                    } // End For Loop               
                } // End Outer If

                else if (e.getSource().equals(buttonExit))
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            } // End method
        } // End inner class 
}// End class
```

Comment: What did you try Cody? You should show your work first then ask questions if you encounter any problems.

Comment: I don't know where to start, that's the problem. I'm pretty new at this

Comment: This is Java. You should be using a proper object, not [parallel arrays](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Comment: I don't like it either, but this was the info I was provided to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example GUI to build the `yearTemp` array's combo box and on selecting a year retrieves corresponding high and low temperatures from the `highLowTemp` array.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class YearTempsTest {
    private static final String [] yearTemp = new String [] {
        "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1956", "1957", "1958",
        "1959", "1960", "1961", "1962", "1963", "1964", "1965", "1966",
        "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974",
        "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982",
        "1983", "1984", "1985", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991",
        "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999",
        "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007",
        "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015",
        "2016"};

    private static final int [] highLowTemp = new int [] {
        7, 68,  9, 77, 20, 65, -7, 63, -3, 66, 8, 62, -2, 63, 3, 58,
        -5, 69, 8, 70, -12, 58, -12, 71, -28, 67, -6, 66, -14, 68, -15, 62,
        10, 73, 0, 64, -12, 60, -14, 66, 7, 67, -8, 71, 0, 62, 13, 69,
        6, 70, -3, 57, -13, 41, -6, 60, 0, 60, 15, 56, -2, 62, -19, 62,
        11, 57, -2, 61, -16, 63, -7, 62, -2, 61, 18, 67,  13, 68, 14, 62,
        4, 58, 12, 67, -32, 54, 3, 69, 7, 68, -2, 68, 6, 66, 4, 73,
        5, 69,  3, 61, 11, 72, -8, 57, 1, 70, 6, 69, 15, 65, 7, 67,
        1, 70, 0, 60, 2, 57, 3, 62, 15, 64, 14, 68, -4, 57, 2, 59,
        5, 64};

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new YearTempsTest().buildGui();
    }

    private void buildGui () {
        JFrame dialog = new JFrame("Year & temps");
        JComboBox<String> yearCombo = new JComboBox<>(yearTemp);
        yearCombo.addItemListener(new YearItemListener());
        dialog.add(yearCombo);  
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setLocation(300, 200);
        dialog.setSize(300, 100);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class YearItemListener implements ItemListener {
        @Override public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                String year = (String) e.getItem();
                // get index of year array
                int ix = Arrays.binarySearch(yearTemp, year, Comparator.naturalOrder());
                // get the high low temps using year array index
                int lowTemp = highLowTemp [ix*2];
                int highTemp = highLowTemp [ix*2 + 1];
                // work with the two temp values (show in a text field, etc.)
                System.out.println(year + " -> " + lowTemp + " :: " + highTemp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Note that it is assumed that the elements of `yearTemp` array are in sorted order (it looks like its already so). This is required for the `binarySearch` to work correctly.

Comment: Hey I added more code to the question. I got the loop understood I think, but I cannot get it to do anything. When I click the calculate button, I get a lot of errors

Comment: `String selectedItem = ((String) comboYearSelector.getSelectedItem());` The value in the `selectedItem` is the selected year from the `yearTemp` array from the combo box. The statement: `int index = Arrays.binarySearch(yearTemp, selectedItem, null);` retrieves the corresponding low and high temps from the `highLowTemp` array. So, you will _not_ need the `for-loop` and the following `if-statement` (may be removed from the `ButtonListener's` code).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this as a comment, but I do not have enough reputation yet, so I am answering instead.

Personally, I'd use some kind of Map for this which could be up to O(1) speed, where as iterating through an array is O(N) (or O(N/2)?). but here is how to get high/low with the data provided. I do not know the ComboBox interface off-hand.

```
void select_year(int year_selected) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < yearTemp.length ++i) {
        if((i* 2) + 1 > highLowTemp.length)
            throw Exception("bad data"); // probably handle this better
        int year = yearTemp[i]
        if(year_selected == year) {
            int low = highLowTemp[i * 2]
            int high = highLowTemp[(i * 2) + 1]
            // this is the high and low for the year_selected
            // do stuff with it
            // edit: break from here when you are done
        }
    }
}
```